# How to execute a "docker run" command in circleci job

Tags: docker, devops, amazon-ecr, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I need to add a circleCI job, after pulling a docker image (abc) i need to execute a "docker run" command on the container which is created by image abc to finish the job.

```
circleci_job:
    docker:
      - image: xyz.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/abc
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: execute docker run command
          command: |
            export env1=https://example.com
            docker run abc --some command
```

I am getting below error:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: docker: command not found
```

I wanted to know if i am using a wrong executer type ? or i am missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here.

1. You need to use an image that has the Docker client already installed or you need to install it on the fly in your job. Right now it appears that the image `xyz.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/abc` doesn't have Docker client installed.
2. With the Docker executor, in order for Docker commands such as `docker run` or `docker pull` to work, you need the special CircleCI step `- setup_remote_docker` to be run BEFORE you try using Docker.